# CQWP xsl to display number column as currency with only 2 decimal places

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am trying to display dollar amounts with 2 decimal places for the "Amount" column. How can I format it to display as $850.00 instead of $850 or $1,974.23 instead of $1974.225 in my code below?

$

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix that formatting of the dollar amounts by adding the following to my calculated column:

=TEXT(BalanceDue,"$#,###.00;($#,###.00)")